# Possible to remove whitespace from php esc_attr in a div.class?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, whitespace

I'm using AffiliateWP with wordpress plus a copy to clipboard plugin.

I am trying to add a line of code that will insert the copy button below each creative's html code.

This is in a loop. The `affwp_creative_atts['id_class']` gives the `div` a unique class based on the ID of the creative(post) example: creative-1

So the php echo is what I coded. The problem is that the function `esc_attr($affwp_creative_atts['id_class'])` adds a whitespace before the period so it doesn't correctly grab the css class.

Is there any way to remove the whitespace before the `esc_attr` function?

The clipboard plugin:
https://es-cr.wordpress.org/plugins/clipboard/

I did try using `str_replace` in the code but it was unsuccessful.

**This was the attempt:**

```
echo '<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="'.str_replace(' '), '.',esc_attr($affwp_creative_atts['id_class']).' pre code"> Copy </button>';

<?php
    $creative = '<a href="' . esc_url( affwp_get_affiliate_referral_url( array( 'base_url' => $affwp_creative_atts['url'] ) ) ) .'" title="' . esc_attr( $affwp_creative_atts['text'] ) . '">' . $image_or_text . '</a>';
    echo '<pre><code>' . esc_html( $creative ) . '</code></pre>';
?>
<?php
echo '<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target=".'.esc_attr($affwp_creative_atts['id_class']).' pre code"> Copy </button>';
?>
```

Here is a screenshot of what the HTML currently outputs: https://snipboard.io/1vgTuf.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have been able to have success using `str_replace`, though I would have to see your implementation of it to know why it wasn't working. Try using `trim` instead:

```
<?php
    $creative = '<a href="' . esc_url( affwp_get_affiliate_referral_url( array( 'base_url' => $affwp_creative_atts['url'] ) ) ) .'" title="' . trim( esc_attr( $affwp_creative_atts['text'] ) ) . '">' . $image_or_text . '</a>';
    echo '<pre><code>' . esc_html( $creative ) . '</code></pre>';
?>
<?php
echo '<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target=".'.trim( esc_attr($affwp_creative_atts['id_class']) ).' pre code"> Copy </button>';
?>
```

Comment: Trim worked. Thanks, Luke!
Not sure why str_replace didn't work either.

Comment: `str_replace` does not work because you closed it too soon. In your example it only takes in 1 argument when it should get 3 arguments. `str_replace(' ', '.', esc_attr($affwp_creative_atts['id_class']))`.